# Compare record count

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i am reading a file which has the TOTAL COUNT as number of records in the end too. Now i need to remove the TOTAL COUNT from the file i.e the last records and then do a count on the dataframe and do a validation check with the TOTAL COUNT for example:

```
colA                    Colb
1                        2
3                        4
total count 000002
```

I am using the below code snippet but the assert error is throwing challenge

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

udf1 = udf(lambda x:x[23:-1],StringType())
df.withColumn('DEST STR',udf1('colA')).display()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temptable")
tableDF = spark.sql("SELECT `colA` FROM temptable order by `colA` desc limit 1")
display(tableDF)
assert df.count() == tableDF.select(udf1("colA"))
```

Note ColA has the Total Count entry record

Comment: what is this: `x[23:-1]`? and how does `df` look like?

Comment: x[23:-1] is for the sub string from the row Total Count 000002 to only consider the numbers or in this case just 2. The DF is as in the example like colA colB and the entries under it

Comment: but what is going on with the last line? does that line belong to the `df`? if so, what's the value in colB? 

also why 23? I don't see 23 characters in that line.

Comment: Yes that belongs to df and total count is only under ColA. ColB has Null in the 3rd row as an entry

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following instead, which avoids the unnecessary use of UDF.

```
assert df.count() - 1 == int(df.select('colA').filter("colA rlike 'total count'").collect()[0][0].split()[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this :

```py
reference_count = int(df.where("colA like 'total count%'").first()["colA"].split()[-1])
total_count = df.count() - 1

assert total_count == reference_count
```